# Relation between the point density of a process $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ and the distribution of $(X_i)_{i\in I}$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, sampling

Let $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ be a measure space, $I$ be a countable set and $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ be an $(E,\mathcal E)$-valued process on a probabiliyty space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$. Assume $$\mu(B):=\left|\left\{i\in I:X_i\in B\right\}\right|=\int_Bp\:{\rm d}\lambda\;\;\;\text{for all }B\in\mathcal E\tag1$$ for some density $p:E\to[0,\infty)$ on $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$.

> How is $p$ related to the distribution of $(X_i)_{i\in I}$? In particular, can we define $p$ in a way such that $(1)$ implies that each $X_i$ has density $q$ with respect to $\lambda$, where $q$ is a given probability density on $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$?

Comment: For any subset of I is$\mu(B)$ defined?

Comment: @herbsteinberg Sorry, I don't understand your question. $I$ is the index set of the process $(X_i)_{i\in I}$. So, we don't consider subsets of $I$ here. For $B\in\mathcal E$, $\mu(B)$ is the (random) number of $i\in I$ for which $X_i\in B$.

Comment: Are all $X_i$ in B or is $\mu(B)$ defined for each $X_i$ ?

Comment: @herbsteinberg Neither the one, nor the other. $\mu(B)$ is a (counting) measure. $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ is fixed. For each set $B$, $\mu(B)$ (more precisely, $\mu(\omega,B)$) is the (random) number (depending on $\omega$) of $i\in I$ for which $X_i\in B$ (i.e. $X_i(\omega)\in B$).

Comment: Looking over the original question:  I can't understand |{$i \in I,,X_i \in B$}|?  Where does the density of $X_i$ come in?

Comment: @herbsteinberg Well, that's the question. It is only assumed that the measure $\mu$ has density $p$.

Comment: What does {$i\in I, X_i\in B$} mean?  What defines its number?  The best guess on my part is that $B$ is a collection of random  variables $(X_i)$, with no numerical meaning.

Comment: @herbsteinberg I don't know how I need to rephrase this, since it is quite elementary mathematics. If $B$ is a set, then $J:=\{i\in I:X_i\in B\}$ is another set. $J$ containts all the $i\in I$ for which the number $X_i$ belong to $B$. Now $\mu(B)$ is simply the cardinality of $B$. In our scenario, $X_i$ is not a "number", but a "random number"; hence it is actually a function on a space $\Omega$. However, this does not anything to the former description of $\mu(B)$, besides the fact that $\mu(B)$ is actually a function on $\Omega$ as well.

Comment: From your description, $\mu(B)$ is the number of elements in I.  The distribution function for $X_i$ seems to have no relevance.

Comment: @herbsteinberg It is the number of elements in $i\in I$ for which $X_i\in B$. So, the distribution of $X_i$ should be highly relevant.

Comment: What seems to be missing is what defines $X_i \in B$

Comment: It looks to me that $X_i$ has a two value distribution $p$ for $X_i\in B$ and $1-p$ for $X_i\notin B$..  Is this what you meant?  If so, is $p$ dependent on $i$?   If constant then $I$ will be finite.

Comment: @herbsteinberg No, $X_i$ can have any distribution. I'm really sorry, but I have no idea why you think it has a binary distribution.

Comment: Your question seems to be asking how many $X_i$ are in $B$.  What underlying distribution $X_i$ has is irrelevant - only is it in $B$.  This leads to the 2 value model I described.

Comment: @herbsteinberg If the distribution of $X_i$ is a Dirac measure,  then $\mu$ will be quite totally different from the case where the distribution of $X_i$ has a normal distribution, for example.

Comment: The differences in $\mu(B)$ depend only on the the differences of $P(X_i\in B)$.  The shape of the distribution won't matter.